# Inserting array elements sequentially into a database java

Tags: java, mysql, arrays

So for example if I have an array list of strings, how do I put them into a database sequentially. 
For example if my array list is: "john", "sally", "rob"
How can I come put that into my database such that row 1 is john, row 2 is sally, row 3 is rob. 
I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){
     query = "insert into database values(i);
}
```

But I am not sure if that is the correct approach because I will also be inserting other values into the database other than the array.

Comment: How are you defining "row"? Do the records have a numeric primary key which defines the row number? And by, *other values... other than the array*, what does that mean exactly? can you provide more informative examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean a simple insertion;

> First you have the database connection, Like this:

```
public class DBConnection {

final private String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/";
final private String databaseName = "test";
final private String user = "root";
final private String password = "159753";

public Connection Connect() {
    Connection c = null;
    try {
        c = DriverManager.getConnection(url + databaseName, user, password);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DBConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return c;
}}
```

> Below is a simple example of insertion:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection con = new DBConnection().Connect();
    String sql = "INSERT INTO nameTable (name) values (?)";
    PreparedStatement stmt;
    try {
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        List<String> names = new ArrayList();
        names.add("John");
        names.add("Sally");
        names.add("Rob");
        for (String name : names) {
            stmt.setString(1, name);
            stmt.execute();
        }
        stmt.close();
        con.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println("Error = " + ex);
    }
}}
```

PS: But you can use a Java Persistence API too. The [wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence) is a good resource to use as reference